# Ошибка: "Использована неинициализированная локальная переменная list"

Tags: c, указатели, список

я пишу программу, где пользователь выбирает определенное действие. В чем проблема: Я не могу скомпилировать, потому что компилятор ругается на потенциальную ошибку: переменная типа DblList (двусвязный список) может быть не инициализирована. У меня в программе есть переменная (DL), которая это отслеживает, поэтому ошибки быть не может. Подскажите, как мне, новичку, обойти данную проблему.

З.Ы Все функции работают корректно, я просто хочу, чтобы только при выборе 7 варианта, пользователю показывался ДС.

```
int main(void) {
    RUS_ON;
    int choose;
    bool DL = 0;  // 0 - список не создан 1 - создан
start:;
    Welcome(&choose);
    DblList* list;
    if (choose == 1) { // этот выбор генерирует список с размером choose елем.
        sayElemCount(&choose); // и заполняет его нулями
        DblList* list = createDblList();
        for (int i = 0; i < choose; i++) {
            int a = 0;
            pushFront(list, &a);
        }
        printf("\nСделано!\n");

        DL = 1; // списко создан
        goto start;
    }
    else if (choose == 7) {
        if (DL == 1)
            printDblList(list, printInt);  // Как избежать потенциальную ошибку в этом месте?
        goto start;
    }
    else
        printf("Потом придумаю\n");
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Спасибо за понимание.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не видите, что `list = createDblList();` -  этот `list` вы тут же теряете, а тут

```
printDblList(list, printInt);
```

вы и в самом деле работаете с неинициализированным `ist`?

Тогда еще раз и медленно:

```
DblList* list;               // НЕИНИЦИАЛИЗИРОВАННАЯ list
if (choose == 1) {
    sayElemCount(&choose);
    DblList* list = createDblList();  // ДРУГАЯ list, не имеющая ничего общего
                                      // с list тремя строками выше!
```

Теперь понятно? Вы объявили ДВЕ РАЗНЫЕ переменные `list`.

Comment: Да, вы правы, это серьезная ошибка. Я исправил эту ее, и инициализировал  DblList list =  NULL. Только после этого скомпилировалось и заработало. Спасибо Вам, очень помогли.